# After complement function can't print a string, and no error message is shown

Tags: python, function, variables

rookie here. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this? I cant seem to print my "primer" string, I am sure that the "region" variable is not empty for I tested it out already.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dVvU.png)

Comment: You should call the function at some time and store its return value

Comment: Please post code as text, not an image of text.

Comment: primer is out of your scope, i.e. that variable is only available inside your function. To get the value outside, just call the function and get the return value

Comment: Thank you for replying, I will make sure to post the code as text next time. @ThomasWeller Would you be generous enough to post a sample of code which calls the function in the comment so I can learn? Sorry again as a rookie.

Comment: @MikeClark has posted a quality answer. If it helped you, you should upvote it. If you think it's the correct answer, add a checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, please post the text of your program, not an image of the program.

I modified your program to do what I think your intent was.

The main thing you needed to do was call complement(region) and assign the return value to a variable.

```
dna = "ATCGATCGATCGTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAG"
print(f"#1 'dna' len={len(dna)} {dna}")

start = "3"
end = "30"
dna = dna[int(start):int(end)]
print(f"#2 'dna' len={len(dna)} {dna}")

region = dna[0:20]
print(f"#2 'region'  len={len(region)} {region}")


def complement(region):
    comp = {'A': 'T', 'T': 'A', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C'}
    primer = ''
    for i in region:
        primer = primer + comp[i]
    return primer

com = complement(region)

print(f"'complement' len={len(com)} {com}")
```

Comment: For added clarity to Mike Clark's useful answer, I would recommend using different names for the global variable region and the variable inside the function also called region; they are different things even if, in this case, they happen to have the same value. It's just good practice.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very clear and very useful! I will make sure to post the code as text next time, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is the fact that you're trying to print the value outside the function, but the variable was defined inside of it, in a smaller scope

Comment: OP would still not call the function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a function complement(), but you have not used this function.
Try assigning the result of your function to a new variable, something like that:

```
dna_compl = complement(region)
print(dna_compl)
```